# How to change Bootstrap Datepicker Anchor Position to center?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Since from Long time I am Struggling for to change Datepicker Anchor Position but didn't get any fix for this problem .

The image of datepicker is given as below,

[image]

Here I want to change anchor position from left to middle is it possible to do that?

I tried to fix it by using Orientation attribute of datepicker , like

```
 $('body').on('focus', "#datepickerDay", function () {
    $(this).datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        endDate: Infinity, format: 'dd-mm-yyyy', orientation: 'auto '
    }).prop('type', 'text').on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        if (Datepickerflag == 0) {
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date);
        splitValidation(newDate);
        Datepickerflag = 1;
    }
    });;
    Datepickerflag = 0;
});
```

And Html Code is,

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.id = "datepickerDay";
        input.style.width = "70px";
        input.style.marginRight = "45px";
        input.style.borderLeft = "none";
        input.style.borderRight = "none";
        input.style.borderTop = "none";
        input.style.borderWidth = "2px";
        input.style.position = "absolute";
        input.style.right = "45px";
        input.style.top = "155px";
        document.getElementById("leftright").appendChild(input);
```

I also tried by applying another option but no attribute i found yet to set anchor position to center.

Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: you mean open the bootstrap and then when the datepicker appears. the anchor has to be in the "month"?

Comment: not Exactly in the month , in the middle of input.

Comment: yes, i tried by applying css.but it wont work.

Comment: can you edit the question with a example snippet of bootstrap datepicker? I think I have the solution

Comment: I need a "working datepicker" that is why I asked you a snippet. You can create a snippet on your edit tools

Comment: hello if you dont mind can you send me your email address, or I have link for datepicker .from here pls copy only code into file. http://www.expertphp.in/article/bootstrap-datepicker-example-text-input-with-specifying-date-format

Comment: When user clicks on input.at that time

Comment: ok sir no problem

Comment: ok ,so are you  fixing it ?, or post it as an answer , I just need hint to resolve issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the anchor to the middle:

1) Create a .css file on your localhost (lets name it "custom.css")
2) Open custom.css
3) Paste these two lines to move the anchor (and it's shadow) of the datepicker from one side to the middle:

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.pull-right:after {
    left: auto;
    right: 50%; 
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.pull-right:before {
    left: auto;
    right: 50%;
}
```

**Note:** The attribute I did changed is **right:50%** before it were in pixels that's why the arrow appeared on a side instead of in the middle.

4) Go to .php file in where you have the datepicker and include your custom.css file on  section. **It has to be after including bootstrap.css**:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="ruta/estilos.css" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>
```

**Note:** You can just open boostrap datepicker .css file and edit it but it's not recommended (it's a bad practice) to modify the original source with your custom styles that's why we create another .css file that will have your own files and the customization of the existing bootstrap styles.

You can see a working example of my code here: [anchor on the middle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8w11qud/3/)

I took as a base **datepicker** of the example provided by [Luis Cruz](https://codepen.io/milz/pen/xbXpWw?editors=1111). There you will find the source of the bootstrap datepicker .css file.

If you have a different **datepicker file** (which implies it will have **different classes** name). You just had to your **browser->developer tools** and then run your site, open the **datepicker** then "select" with the developer tools **the anchor from the datepicker** and in the right part of the developer tools window you will how is it named the anchor in your **bootstrap datepicker css file**.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I just want to change the anchor position from left to middle. that's it. as i just checked the exaple its appearing to the right.

Comment: can i use internal css as well?

Comment: No problem bro!